# Hi :) I have a question about Taylor series and convergence.

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

My function is $f(x)= \sqrt{1+\sin x}$ around $x_0=0$ .
Taylor series should look like (I guess so)

$f^{(2n)}(x)=\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{2n}}f(x) \quad\to\quad f^{(2n)}(0)=\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{2n}}$

$f^{(2n+1)}(x)=\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{2n+1}}f'(x)\quad\to\quad f^{(2n+1)}(0)=\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{2n+1}}$

I don't really understand how to show when it converges. I want to find out how will be x defined if exists a $\lim_{n\to\infty} T_n(x)$

Thank you.

Comment: How did you get those formulas for the derivatives?

Comment: Why do you believe those expressions are correct?

Comment: At first I solved it at the university and now I also found the same answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2015450/taylor-series-fx-sqrt1-sin-x-around-x-0-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your derivatives you got $|f^{(k)}(0)|=2^{-k}$. This means that the term-wise absolute series of the Taylor expansion is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left|\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k\right|=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{|x/2|^k}{k!}=e^{|x|/2}
$$
which is finite for all $x\in\Bbb R$. Thus the Taylor expansion of $f$ is everywhere absolutely convergent.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Note that your function $f(x)=\sqrt{1+\sin x}$ is the composit function of $\sqrt{1+x}$ and $\sin x$

The Taylor series for $\sqrt {1+x}$ converges for $|x|\le 1$ and we have $|\sin x|\le 1$ for all $x$

Thus your power series converges on $(-\infty,\infty)$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it means I have to find the taylor series of $\sqrt {1+x}$ at first and then to show that it converges for $|x|\le 1$ right? Or is it so clear, that it don't have to be proved? (However I don't understand it completely)

Comment: It is binomial series which is well known to converge on $[-1,1]$

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Thanks for your attention.